# Angular JS TypeScript IHttpService inject custom header value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, header, typescript

I have a project where I make successful Http Get request **from TypeScript** (Angular HTTP Service) code **to Web API controller** and display the list in a grid. The project is using Angular JS 1.4.x and TypeScript successfully.

**Full Project's [GitHub URL](https://github.com/foyzulkarim/VirtualTechAcademy/tree/master/Practices/AngularTypeScriptApps/AngularTypeScriptApps.App3).** and the TypeScript code which calls to the server  is below.

```
module App {
    export class StudentListService {
        private qService: ng.IQService;
        private httpService: ng.IHttpService;

        constructor($q: ng.IQService, $http: ng.IHttpService) {
            this.qService = $q;        
            this.httpService = $http;
        }

        get(): ng.IPromise<Object[]> {
            var self = this;
            var deffered = self.qService.defer();            
            self.httpService.get('/api/values').then((result: any): void => {
                if (result.status === 200) {
                    deffered.resolve(result.data);
                } else {
                    deffered.reject(result);
                }
            }, error => {
                deffered.reject(error);
            });

            return deffered.promise;
        }
    }

    StudentListService.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];
    angular.module('app').service('StudentListService', StudentListService);
}
```

***Now, I want to add a custom header with the get request call.*** I have tried many ways, but TypeScript keep giving me build error. Any help or work around would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: its build error. no method or property of the interface takes header values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you are using correct typing file for angular you should be able to add header as a part of config, second argument which is of type `ng.IRequestShortcutConfig` which is an extension of `IHttpProviderDefaults` that has the `header` property.

> `get<T>(url: string, config?: IRequestShortcutConfig): IHttpPromise<T>;`

Also added much simplified code.

```
      export class StudentListService {

        static $inject = ['$q', '$http'];

        constructor(private qService: angular.IQService, 
                    private httpService: angular.IHttpService) { }

        get(): angular.IPromise<Object[]> {

            //Example of config structure
            var config: angular.IRequestShortcutConfig = {
                headers: {
                    "someheader":"somevalue"
                }
            }
            //add config and just return the promise directly instead of creating a deferred object. Promises are chainable
            return this.httpService.get('/api/values', config)
              .then((result: any) => result.data);

              //If you want to catch then use ".catch" instead of second argument to the "then" which is a better practice as any error that may happen inside your code in the then block will be caught as well.
        }
    }
```